# Creating a log in view page with Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to create a login view page to go throuhg the process of authenticating and logging in a user without mixins or decorators. I have the following code:

`urls.py:`

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name="home"),
  path('accounts/login/', views.login_view, name="login"),
```

`views.py:`

```py
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("logged in!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("invalid credentials")
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

`templates/registration/login.html:`

```py
{% block content %}
<h1>Log in!</h1>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

When I try to access the `accounts/login` page my table doesn't show up unfortuantely. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you do template enheritance. If you define a block without the inheriting item providing a `content` block, it will not include it in the final data.

Comment: I guess you want to use the `django.contrib.auth` login mechanism? Please share your full code so that we can see the full template and full view. The view for example is missing initiating and setting the `AuthenticationForm` in the context in case you want to use `django.contrib.auth`.

Answer (score 0):

you're not passing any form to the context in the render() function, it should be something like:

```
...
return render(request, "registration/login.html", {"form": YouLoginForm()})
```